# How to create a flipping on hover image slider?

Tags: wordpress, slider, nivo-slider

Hello I've seen this cool slider

http://jddmarketing.com/

I was wondering how could you do that ? I tried inspecting the element but my knowledge is a bit limited an wasn't able to find the necessary info.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What did you do so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the flip demo here :-

```
http://codepen.io/jjhesk/pen/lHdCA/
```

Comment: Is there any plugin for wordpress to input this technique ?